# Assiging an xml query result to a variable

Tags: c#, xml, linq, variables

my xml looks something like this:

```
<x>
  <y a1= "abc" a2= "xyz" a3="2" a4="4" a5="8"/>
  <y a1= "def" a2= "hij" a3="5" a4="10" a5="15"/>
</x>
```

The following code filters the values of my xml and prints the result to screen:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                int first;
                int second;
                int third;
                XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(xmlFile);
                IEnumerable<XElement> rows = from row in doc.Descendants("x")
                                             where row.Attribute("a1").ToString() == "abc" & row.Attribute("a2").ToString() == "xyz"
                                             select row;
                foreach (XElement ele in rows)
                {
                    IEnumerable<XAttribute> aList = from att in ele.DescendantsAndSelf().Attributes()
                                                    select att;
                    foreach (XAttribute xatr in atrList)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(att);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Instead of displaying the result to the screen I want to assign the values a3, a4 and a5 of the filtered row to the variables first, second and third. I also want to overwrite the values at a3, a4 and a5 with new values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(xmlFile);
            IEnumerable<XElement> rows = from row in doc.Descendants("x")
                                         where row.Attribute("a1").ToString() == "abc" & row.Attribute("a2").ToString() == "xyz"
                                         select row;

            int first;
            int second;
            int third;

            foreach (XElement ele in rows)
            {
                Int32.TryParse(ele.Attribute("a3").Value, out first);
                Int32.TryParse(ele.Attribute("a4").Value, out second);
                Int32.TryParse(ele.Attribute("a5").Value, out third);

                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", first, second, third);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to overwrite the values at a3, a4 and a5 with values from other variables, would you know how to do that? I have a feeling ele.Attribute("a3") = new value won't quite do it.

Comment: I think `ele.Attribute("a3").Value = "new value";` will exactly do it!

Answer (score 0):

You can just set them to your filtered row based on their index. Replace your inner foeach() loop with:

```
IEnumerable<XAttribute> aList = (from att in ele.DescendantsAndSelf().Attributes()
                                                    select att).ToList();
first = atrList[2];
second = atrList[3];
third = atrList[4];
```

Comment: When i try this i get an error saying "cannot apply indexing with [] to expression of type 'System.Collection.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute'"?

Comment: My mistake, I didn't see that you'd assigned it to IEnumerable. If you cast it with .ToList() as shown in my example you should be able to index it. That said, Paul provides a better solution that will work even if your attributes are out of order.